# Why does my url localhost:8080////ProjectCtxt/mvc/template works?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, web

Following is my spring MVC web application.

1) I don't know why my application with four forward slashes after port number works. How to fix this.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ProjectCtxt.www.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <!--   <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" /> -->

      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>                       
                </list>
            </property>        
        </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver"/>

        <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass">
                <value>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
                </value>
            </property>
        </bean>  

</beans>
```

appContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- MVC context is separate from the app context usually. -->

    <!-- component scan is not recursive -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ProjectCtxt.www.service" />

    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="tableName" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.2" id="WebApp_ID">

    <!-- <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

ProjectController.java

```
package com.ProjectCtxt.www.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.ProjectCtxt.www.service.ProjectService;

@Controller("resultController")
public class ResultController {

    private final ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    public ProjectController(ProjectService projectService) {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value ="/template", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersonList(ModelMap model) {

        return   "header";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudentResult(String rNo, ModelMap model){
        return "numberResult";
    }
}
```

2) Also when I am working on my project in my local machine I always use loclahost:8080/ProjectCtxt/mvc/template but when I deploy in production I want it to be mywebsite.com . How can I do this?

2a) When I tried `www.google.com////calendar/render`, it works. But when I type `www.google.com/calendar////render` it doesn't work.

3) If I use localhost:8080/ProjectCtxt/mvc/template  I go to homepage. When I click search button in my jsp, my url becomes `http://localhost:8080/search?regNo`. But if I manually change `localhost:8080/search?regNo=`    to   `localhost:8080/ProjectCtxt/mvc/search?regNo=`  it works? Why is this? How can I fix the url to automatically be `localhost:8080/ProjectCtxt/mvc/search?regno=`  rather than typing "ProjectCtxt/mvc/search?regNo=" manually

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC    
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"   
     "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">


<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Lets see"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp  "/>
        <put-attribute name="center" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" /> 
    </definition>

    <definition name="header" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp" />  
    </definition>


    <!-- <definition name="bottom" extends="new.template">
        <put-attribute name="bottom" value="/mvc/jsp/ads.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="bottom" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp" />
    </definition> -->

</tiles-definitions>
```

header.jsp

```
<%-- <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <center>
    <h1>Header</h1></center>


        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
     </body>
 </html> --%>



    <form action="/search" method="GET" >
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="ABCD"></input> or 
            <input  id="collName" type="text" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="EFGH"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit"  value="search"><br/>

        </div>




    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

About the / character:
Tomcat just ignores the extra / characters. Only the part after the context path is routed to your application. It's up to each web server to decide how they treat it, so Google does it differently and that cannot be compared.

About hosting on your own domain:
This is usually done with a separate server in front, and not Tomcat directly.
For example, with nginx: [Nginx configuration to pass site directly to tomcat webapp with context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866203/nginx-configuration-to-pass-site-directly-to-tomcat-webapp-with-context)

About the incorrect URL in the form action:
Since you're using plain HTML,  is not translated to the real location which is /ProjectCtxt/search - which is the case even if the @RequestMapping refers to /search .

Using standard JSTL Core, the "c:url" tag will automatically add the context path.
Another option is to use the Spring Form tags which post to the beans and automatically generate the proper paths.

Comment: "About the incorrect URL in the form action: Since you're using plain HTML, is not translated to the real location which is /ProjectCtxt/search - which is the case even if the @RequestMapping refers to /search ."

So, What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Something like the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235689/jstl-curl-not-working-with-form-action